# Python. Django. Persistent socket.io connection

Tags: python, django, socket.io

Is there any way to connect to socket.io server and keep connection alive, like js client do, from django backend?

Code like this:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
from django.conf import settings

def trigger_socket():
   socket_client = SocketIO(settings.SIO_HOST, settings.SIO_PORT)
   socket_client.emit('cool_task', {})
```

Works fine, but opens connection at every task emit. Is there any way to avoid it? Or I'm missing something about sockets?

**UPD FYI** Actually, usage of socket.io to communicate between servers - was stupid idea. Use tornadorpc / xmlrpclib for this kind of task - leave socket.io only on js client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brief:

It's not possible in the way you described. If you want to use django to connect to the  something like socket.io, take a look at [gevent.io](http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Detailed:

When deployed with traditional web server, Django is not suitable to handle long time connection tasks due to the process/thread model. To handle long time connection, you need to adopt some event driven web server, such as [gunicorn][2]

Comment: I'm using this connection in celery task. Can I define connection for master celery process?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with celery. But generally if you want to re-use a single connection to handle multiple things, you can create a connection and a task queue, setup a queue handler, and push new tasks to the queue when they come in.

Comment: That's what celery for. Ok, I will take a look at gunicorn for current task. Not sure if will add another lib in the zoo. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with :

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO
from django.conf import settings

def trigger_socket():
    with SocketIO(settings.SIO_HOST, settings.SIO_PORT) as socketIO:
        socketIO.emit('cool_task', {})
        socketIO.wait(seconds=0)
```